# Solarized theme + Yakuake + VIM in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: vim, konsole

I've already searched for answers about Yakuake/Konsole and Solarized theme, but all discussions seems to be gnome-terminal-centric.

As in title,

#### `~/.vimrc~`

```
" sets colorscheme
set t_Co=16
set background=dark
let g:solarized_termcolors=16
let g:solarized_termtrans = 1
colorscheme solarized
```

#### `~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fradeve fradeve 1040 Jul 31 10:57 SolarizedDark.colorscheme
```

from github.com/eternicode/konsole-colors-solarized (sorry but due to lack of reputation I cannot post more than two links).

#### moreover

- SolarizedDark colorscheme correctly set in Yakuake config
- Yakuake has been restarted to refresh settings
- vim runs plain, not in tmux
- commenting out `let g:solarized_termcolors=16` does not solve the problem

and results are slightly different from the color theme displayed. I'll take JavaScript as example:

Original theme:
[original solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/screen-javascript-dark.png)

My solarized konsole
[my solarized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjLPq.png)

It seems to me a wasting of author's talent to use such "distorted" colors.

Comment: sorry, actually there's [Phiggins' theme](https://github.com/phiggins/konsole-colors-solarized/blob/master/Solarized%20Dark.colorscheme) for Konsole which fits enough with the original Colorized theme

Answer (score 2):

this problem is solved set to .vimrc :
**let g:solarized_termcolors=256**
see - https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users

Comment: Thank you cementonovoz, but simply I found not acceptable that is not possibile to configure correctly Konsole, Vim and Solarized toghether, after all Konsole is a _modern_ terminal emulator. I've found that trying more "Solarized" theme solved the issue, since among them available online some fits enough. Plus, I don't want to degrade the work on readability done on Solarized. Thank you anyway :)